# How do I open hex file in java?

Tags: java, file-io, binary

So I wrote this little class that is supposed to open file and output it to screen. My file is hex file so when I open it in notepad it outputs random characters that depends on encoding. So I figured I have to convert it to binary first and then output(I want it in binary anyway).

However java gives me an error while converting and shows that it is being interpreted as text.

Whats wrong?

Class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.*;


public class fileClass {

    private Scanner s;
    private String content;

    public void openFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            s = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));
            content = s.next();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            s.close();
        }
    }


    public String HexToBinary(String Hex) {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(Hex, 16);
        String Bin = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
        return Bin;
    }

    public void output() {
        System.out.println(HexToBinary(content));
    }
}
```

error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "tîxl¸?
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at fileClass.HexToBinary(fileClass.java:29)
    at fileClass.output(fileClass.java:36)
    at test.main(test.java:8)
```

Comment: ťîxł is not a hex code...

Comment: I know - Java is interpreting this as utf8 or something how do I tell her(?) to interpret it as hex?

Comment: Dont use scanner - it is looking for ASCII strings - use a DataInputStream instead.

Comment: Forget about scanners... they're only used by students!

Comment: What is a hex file? What is a binary file? It seems that your file is already what i would call a binary file (i.e.: the bytes in it are not limited to printable ("displayable by Notepad") ASCII codes). Please state more clearly what you are trying to do. Give a sample of the input and of the expected output.

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'hex file'. What you have is a binary file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a scanner or FileReader as they are text based. I guess you want to just read a binary file and [FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) should suffice.

Comment: Omg there is so many classes in java for I/O - its super confusing. In C++ I had few streams and one method.

Comment: Yep. But the most important thing is to know if you want to use InputStream or a Reader based on the type of the data. After that, you pretty much can guess the wrapper or implementation classes that can be used.